# How to view revision history with values provided in kubernetes-helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm

`helm history <release name>` but there's no option to see what values are used in each release history. How can I do that?

Answer (score 26):

you can download the values for any given release and revision. There are two options I've used `helm get` and `helm get values`. For example:

```
helm get values --revision=12 crafty-badger
```

For details see the docs[1](https://docs.helm.sh/helm/#helm-get-values)